# How would I set a model property to the result of an extension's method?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, model

I have a data model consisting of a couple of properties and methods, this data model inherits from an interface. However, I've now created a static extension and would like to set one of my model properties to the result of that extension method.

These are my models and extensions:

**PublishedContentModel**:

```
namespace CMS.Core.Models
{
    public class PublishedContentModel : IPublishedContent
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The id of this node.
        /// </summary>
        public Int32 Id { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// The name of this node.
        /// </summary>
        public String Name { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// The url path.
        /// </summary>
        public String Path { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// This nodes document id.
        /// </summary>
        public Int32 DocumentId { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// The parent node's id.
        /// </summary>
        public IPublishedContent Parent { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// The collection of this node's children.
        /// </summary>
        public IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> Children { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// The collection of ancestors.
        /// </summary>
        public IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> Ancestors ()
        {
            IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> colContentNodes = ContentService.GetAllContentNodes();
            List<IPublishedContent> colAncestors = new List<IPublishedContent>();

            foreach (IPublishedContent objContentNode in colContentNodes.Where(x => x.Descendants().Any(y => y.Id == Id)))
            {
                colAncestors.Add(objContentNode);
            }

            return colAncestors;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// The collection of all nodes under this.
        /// </summary>
        public IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> Descendants ()
        {
            // - Get the children and create a collection for descendants.
            IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> colChildren = Children;
            List<IPublishedContent> colDescendants = new List<IPublishedContent>();

            if (colChildren.Any())
            {
                colDescendants = colChildren.ToList();

                foreach (IPublishedContent objChild in colChildren)
                {
                    IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> colChildsChildren = objChild.Children;

                    // - Check if this node has children.
                    if (colChildsChildren.Any())
                    {
                        colDescendants.AddRange(colChildsChildren);
                    }
                }
            }

            return colDescendants;
        }
    }
}
```

**ContentModelExtensions**:

```
namespace CMS.Core.Models
{
    public static class ContentModelExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> Children (this IPublishedContent Content)
        {
            IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> colContentNodes = ContentService.GetAllContentNodes();
            List<IPublishedContent> colChildren = new List<IPublishedContent>();

            foreach (IPublishedContent objContentNode in colContentNodes.Where(x => x.Parent != null))
            {
                colChildren.Add(objContentNode);
            }

            return colChildren;
        }
        public static IEnumerable<T> Children<T> (this IPublishedContent Content) where T : class, IPublishedContent
        {
            IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> colContentNodes = ContentService.GetAllContentNodes();
            List<T> colChildren = new List<T>();

            foreach (T objContentNode in colContentNodes.Where(x => x.Parent != null))
            {
                colChildren.Add(objContentNode);
            }

            return colChildren;
        }
    }
}
```

The issue with this code is that I can't do `Children.Any()` seeing as the `IEnumerable` for this is null. I tried fixing this by setting the `Children` property when it gets sent to the view, like this:

```
objContentNode = new PublishedContentModel ()
{
    Id         = Convert.ToInt32(objReader["Id"]),
    Name       = Convert.ToString(objReader["Name"]),
    Parent     = GetContentNodeById(Convert.ToInt32(objReader["ParentId"])),
    Path       = Convert.ToString(objReader["Path"]),
    DocumentId = Convert.ToInt32(objReader["DocumentId"]),
    Children   = ContentModelExtensions.Children(objContentNode)
};
```

Put that just makes the connection timeout, any help would be appreciated. Let me know if I haven't explained my issue well enough.

**TLDR:**
I want to set `public IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> Children { get; set; }` to the result of `ContentModelExtensions.Children()`

Comment: ``ContentService.GetAllContentNodes()`` do you have any idea about number of lines returned by this call? you can do that without extension method, because you don't use ``Content`` inside function.

Comment: Hi, I'm aware of how many nodes that are in the database. This eventually will have a limit. The `ContentService` is just a class with some static functions. I tried setting `Children` by doing this `public IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> Children => this.Children()` which doesn't give me an editor error but does give me a YSOD.

Comment: The `ContentService` will allow you to get things like properties, pages, children, ancestors etc. and `CMSService` is just used for the back-office. Displaying things like documents, templates, etc. to the user.

Comment: It may be to do with the `ContentService` as that's what the extension uses for `Children()` so whenever I try and set the Children to `Children()` it just keeps looping. Any ideas @Sajid?

Comment: try to delete the parameter in the extension method ``Children`` and keep just one ``children`` method. may be you need too to change the property ``public IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> Children`` to ``static``

Comment: That would work, but I want the method and property.